# Error con LocalStorage en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple modo dark pero trato de que quede al refrescar la pagina no se pierda el modo seleccionado.

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
const toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
        toggle.onclick = function () {
            sec.classList.toggle('dark')

            localStorage.setItem('sec', 'dark')
        }
```

```css
body.sec {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

body.dark {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body class="sec">
    <div class="toggle">click</div>
    <h1>Texto</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu implementación tiene buena pinta!
Pero te faltaba abordar el caso que dicho valor existe en local storage para hacer uso de este.
Comparto código de ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body.sec {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
    }

    body.dark {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .theme-toggle {
      padding: 8px 16px;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
  <body class="sec">
    <h1>Theme changer</h1>
    <button class="theme-toggle" onclick="toggleClasses()">Toogle Theme</button>
    <script>
      function toggleClasses() {
        const sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
        sec.classList.toggle('dark');

        localStorage.setItem('sec', 'dark');
      }

      const sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
      const existDarkClass = localStorage.getItem('sec');
      if (!!existDarkClass) sec.classList.toggle('dark');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Victor, pero trate de hacer algo asi y cuando quiero volver al modo normal que `light` no me deja

Comment: Comparto código de ejemplo ejecutable en mi respuesta. Sólo tienes que presionar el botón para cambiar entre temas, pero lo que realmente está haciendo es agregar/quitar la clase dark al body.

Comment: Gracias Victor!